# Error while initializing dynamic array in System Verilog

Tags: system-verilog, dynamic-arrays

I want to return a dynamic array from a function. But I am getting error while declaring dynamic array. Can someone please help me with how to define it. I have few specific doubts

1. If my return type is dynamic array(out_data), do I need to allocate memory space like this: `pre_processing= new [temp_i.len()]`
2. I am getting an error while declaring `bit temp_i_b[]`, do I need to do it in some other way?
3. To return the data (dynamic array in this case), do we need to use `return` keyword?

Any help in this context is highly appreciable.

```
  module test1();

typedef  bit [511:0] out_data[];

string a="A";

function out_data pre_processing(string temp_i);


     bit temp_i_b[];
     int k,d_zero,l;
     bit d[];
     bit tempor[];
     out_data temp_out;
     int n;
     int T=0;
     int i=0;
     int size;
     pre_processing= new [temp_i.len()]  ; 
     temp_i_b=new[24](temp_i_b);

size =(temp_i.len())*4'd8;
$display(size);
$display(temp_i);
$display("%b",temp_i.atobin());//
foreach(temp_i_b[i]) begin
  temp_i_b[i]=temp_i.atobin()[i];

//temp[3:0]=4'b1111
foreach(temp_i_b[i])
  $display("temp[%d]=%d\n",i,temp_i_b[i]);
end
     d=new[10](d);



     temp_out=new [3] (temp_out);

     tempor=new [512*3] (tempor);



    l=temp_i.len()*8;//l=24
    k=447-l;

     if(k<0)
      k=512+k;


     do
     begin
      d[i]=l%2;
      l=l/2;
      i++;             
     end while(l>0);

     T=l+1+k+d.size();
     n=T/512;
      d_zero=n*512-T;         
      temp_i_b={temp_i_b,1'b1};
foreach(tempor[i])      
  tempor[i]= temp_i_b << (k+d_zero);
     foreach(d[i])
     tempor[tempor.size()-1:0]={tempor[tempor.size()-1:0],d[d.size()-i-1]};

     //end      
     foreach(tempor[i]) begin  
      foreach(temp_out[i]) begin        
        while(tempor[$size(tempor)-1:0]!=0) begin
          temp_out[i]=tempor[$size(tempor)-1:$size(tempor)-512];
     tempor[$size(tempor)-1:0]=tempor[$size(tempor)-1:0] << 512;
      end
      end
     end

      foreach(temp_out[i])
      return temp_out;
      endfunction


out_data my_q;
initial begin

  my_q=pre_processing("111");

  $display("%d",a.atoi());
  $display("output=%b",my_q[0]);
    end


  endmodule
```

Comment: There are several syntax errors and it doesn't look like you understand how arrays work in SystemVerilog. Review [IEEE 1800-2012](http://standards.ieee.org/getieee/1800/download/1800-2012.pdf) sections 7.5 through 7.12. What are you trying to achieve (end goal, not the specific compiling error)?

Answer (score 0):

> If my return type is dynamic array(out_data), do I need to allocate memory space like this(pre_processing= new [temp_i.len()] )

Yes. You would need to allocate memory to it.

> I am getting an error while declaring bit temp_i_b[],do I need to do it in some other way ?

You would need to declare all the variables before `pre_processing= new [temp_i.len()];`

There are few other errors as well -

- You cannot access a dynamic array without an index: `tempor[]=temp_i_b << (k+d_zero);`
- I don't think that such assignments are allowed - `my_q=pre_processing(temp_i="ABC");` Or were you trying to do an equality check?
- Your `typedef` statements seems a bit odd - `typedef  bit [511:0] out_data[];` I don't think there is a need of `[]` at the end of out_data.

> To return the data (dynamic array in this case),do we need to use "return" keyword ?

No, if it is globally accessible otherwise yes.

Comment: Thanks for all your help. I rectified the points mentioned by you and it worked. Have another doubt                                                                                               I am passing an ASCII string to the function and trying to convert it to its binary value. But the built-in function 'atobin()' is not working in this case. do you have any suggestion on that?